# How to keep shape text but not show it?

Tags: vba, ms-word

My firm uses MS Azure Information Protection to attach privacy labels to documents.

When we send customer letters, the label shouldn't be visible. We select the Shape object the label is stored in, and set text fill to 'no fill', so the letter does not show the label. The but document still has the privacy setting embedded for internal retention.

Due to volumes this needs to be automated.

I cannot see anything in `Shapes.TextFrame.TextRange` that duplicates the 'no fill'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for

```
ActiveDocument.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor
```

but I'm not aware of a "no fill" property for that. You could make the text the same color as it's background. But instead, try making the text hidden:

```
ActiveDocument.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Hidden = True
```

Comment: Comparing the 'before' and 'after' values in Locals, thevofrecolor and hidden values did not change - but the transparency, type and visible properties of font.fill did change from 0, msofillsolid, msotrue  to 1, msofullmixed, msofalse respetively.  Many thanks for the steer, embarrassecd to say I never looked in the font area.